# How to define a function that operate with a base case recursively?

Tags: functions, recursion

Let's start from the simplest case: say I have a function $f(x)=x$, and let's say I want to define a new function (of $x$) to be its $n$-th power $(f(x))^n$. How should I write the code? I tried:

```
f[n_, x_] := f[n - 1, x]*f[n - 1, x]
f[1, x] = x
```

But the result is much different from what I wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
f[x_] := x^2
f[x_, n_] := Nest[f[#] &, x, n]

f[2]
f[2, 3]

(* 
4
256
*)
```

Comment: @francis: Thanks for accept. Note you can write the `Nest` as `Nest[f, x, n]`, I put in all the gory guts to make it (perhaps) more clear.

Comment: Just a note that in the original there is an underscore missing and would be better using SetDelayed, so f[1,x_]:=x. This does I think what the OP intended (though rasher's answer is better).